# Wireshark--Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 51589, Dst Port: 443, Seq: 599, Ack: 6627, Len: 0

Tags: wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I am getting a red message in wireshark mentioning the following:

Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 51589, Dst Port: 443, Seq: 599, Ack: 6627, Len: 0

Any idea what does that mean?The ones in Red looks like something is wrong[image: Screenshot of the issue]

Any help in understanding the issue would be appreciated.
Note: I referred a few questions on the topic but could not find anything specific.